# String split and join get strings from database

Tags: javascript, database, string, join, split

I have a working java script with split and join function, but the data I have is giving me an error code of "exceeding the limit" so i decided to use a database to store strings and get strings from there.. my existing java script code is here.

```
 function myFunction()
 {
    var str = document.getElementById("entryInput");
    var entryId = str.value;
    var str = (entryId); 
    var res = str.split('how are you brother').join('how r u bro')
    .split('are you ok').join('r u ok')
    .split('what is going on').join('wag one');
    document.getElementById('translation').innerHTML=res;
 };
```

I searched and found this database connection related lines but after I tried many times I couldn't make it work so please help me...

```
@mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PWD) or die(mysql_error());
@mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) or die(mysql_error());

$str = "SELECT * FROM words WHERE word_title= "%$_GET[word]%";
$str = mysql_query($query);
```

edited and added....

This is the PHP code that came with the script and it gets strings from database word by word but I want as javascript did for me. get the word split and join again which will make a continues strings... all i need to get is getting strings from this database and use it in jscript if possible... if the user types a word i need it to get it from the database... here is the link to the page that the user will use..[Page that the user will type string like of different words stored in the database](http://raadso.so/translate/)
it currently translates only "are you ok" to "r u ok" which is in the javascript file. so i need it to get it from database thanks

```
function Search() {
    global $rewrite;

    $_GET['word'] = trim(str_replace(Array('%', '_'), Array('', ''), $_GET['word']));

    if ($_GET['type']) {
        $word = 'noword';
        $type = $_GET['type'];
    } elseif ($_GET['by']) {
        $word = $_GET['by'];
        $type = '';
    } elseif ($_GET['word']) {
        $word = $_GET['word'];
        if ($_GET['type'] == 'full') $type = 'full';
        else $type = '';
    } else {
        $word = '';
        $type = '';
    }

    if ($word != '') {
        $GLOBALS['page_title'] = $_GET['word'] .  ' - ' . $GLOBALS['page_title'];
        if ($type == 'full') {
            $select = "* ";
            $where = "word_title LIKE '%$_GET[word]%' OR word_desc LIKE '%$_GET[word]%' ";
            $order = "word_id DESC ";
        } elseif($type == 'latest') {
            $select = '* ';
            $where = "word_title LIKE '%$_GET[word]%' ";
            $order = "word_id DESC ";
        } else {
            $select = '* ';
            $where = "word_title LIKE '" . sqlesc($word) . "%' ";
            $order = "word_title ASC ";
        }
        $q = "SELECT $select FROM `words` WHERE $where ORDER BY $order ";
    } else {
        Redirect('index.php');
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Ham is to Hamster

Comment: `Java` != `JavaScript` if you are not sure which tag to use just read its description.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$str = "SELECT * FROM words WHERE word_title LIKE "%$_GET[word]%";
```

Or

```
$str = "SELECT * FROM words WHERE word_title REGEXP "$_GET[word]";
```

Comment: so how will  function myFunction() get the string from the database that is what I need thanks

Comment: so i guess i will use the get element lik this...

var str = document.getElementById("%$_GET[word]%");

and the database like this...

$str = "SELECT * FROM words WHERE word_title LIKE "entryInput";

is it something like this please correct me.

Comment: No its $str = "SELECT * FROM words WHERE word_title LIKE "%$_GET[word]%"

Comment: What does your sql table look like. And what should happen with the user inputs?

Comment: I edited my question since my instructions are more... please check again thanks